# Custom Jpa Repository erroring with Fragment implementation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am currently writing an application in spring boot and am building my own custom repository.

First things first, here the code in question:

```java
@Repository
public interface ServiceRepository<T extends ServiceEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, UUID>, ServiceRepositoryCustom {
}

public interface ServiceRepositoryCustom {
    List<ServiceEntity> findAllWithParams(String query);
}

public class ServiceRepositoryImpl implements ServiceRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<ServiceEntity> findAllWithParams(String query) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ServiceEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(ServiceEntity.class);

        Root<ServiceEntity> serviceEntity = cq.from(ServiceEntity.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if(query != null)  {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(serviceEntity.get("name"), query));
        }
        cq.where(predicates.toArray(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}
```

After launching the application, it fails with following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Registry' defined in file [/home/awesomedude091/Desktop/ViralManager/Core/build/classes/java/main/com/viralinnovation/viralmanager/Plugins/Registry.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JVMServiceRepository' defined in com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.JVMServiceRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ViralManagerApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#34cb0e49' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'repositoryFragments'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#34cb0e49': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRepositoryImplFragment': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment]: Factory method 'implemented' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment implementation com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepositoryImpl does not implement com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepository!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.master.ViralManagerApplication.main(ViralManagerApplication.java:25) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JVMServiceRepository' defined in com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.JVMServiceRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ViralManagerApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#34cb0e49' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'repositoryFragments'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#34cb0e49': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRepositoryImplFragment': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment]: Factory method 'implemented' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment implementation com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepositoryImpl does not implement com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepository!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#34cb0e49': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRepositoryImplFragment': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment]: Factory method 'implemented' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment implementation com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepositoryImpl does not implement com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepository!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRepositoryImplFragment': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment]: Factory method 'implemented' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment implementation com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepositoryImpl does not implement com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepository!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment]: Factory method 'implemented' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment implementation com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepositoryImpl does not implement com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepository!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment implementation com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepositoryImpl does not implement com.viralinnovation.viralmanager.Services.Entities.Repositories.ServiceRepository!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:139) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment$ImplementedRepositoryFragment.lambda$new$1(RepositoryFragment.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment$ImplementedRepositoryFragment.<init>(RepositoryFragment.java:203) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment.implemented(RepositoryFragment.java:67) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 61 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Note: This setup previously worked with a JPA Repository, so it is not the issue of the services calling it, it is the fault of the new Service Repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA repository scan by default looks for implementations with post fix string for class, which is `Impl` (it could be changed if you need).

When you want to add custom behaviour to a JPA repository by an 'extension', you need to follow:
ExtensionName (interface) -> EntensionNameImpl (class).

In your case `ServiceRepositoryImpl implements ServiceRepositoryCustom` is wrong, you need to rename `ServiceRepositoryImpl  to ServiceRepositoryCustomImpl`; because in this case Spring expects `ServiceRepositoryImpl` to be a `ServiceRepository`

Take a look on https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations .

(Off-topic) When you enabled Spring JPA repository scan, you should not need `@Repository` annotation, because `extends JpaRepository` marks the interface as repository for you; if you go look its dependency hierarchy you find a `Repository` interface on top.